# Why does my HomeScreen's ngOninit() hit when I navigate from one page but not hit when I navigate from another page in ionic?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my ionic project I have 3 pages: **HomeScreen**, **SearchPage** & **ScannerPage**.

I navigate to **SearchPage** & **ScannerPage** from my **HomeScreen** via a routerlink as in my examples below:

```
<ion-button routerLink="/manual-qr-search" color= "tertiary" expand="block">Check Out</ion-button>
<ion-button disabled={{this.myService.getTempCardDisabled()}} routerLink="/manual-temperature-scanner" color= "primary" expand="full" class="flex-child"><ion-icon name="keypad-outline"></ion-icon>MANUAL</ion-button>
```

and I navigate back to the **HomeScreen** from my **SearchPage** using the android back button as follows:

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(99999, () => {  
  this.router.navigate(['home-screen']);
});
```

and I navigate back to the **HomeScreen** from my **ScannerPage** using the android back button as follows:

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(99999, () => { 
  this.router.navigate(['home-screen']);
});
```

My problem is the **HomeScreen's** ngOnInit() hits when I navigate from **SearchPage** but it doesn't hit when I navigate from **ScannerPage** and I want to know why.

I do not call ngOnDestroy() at all on any page.

I can put in a check to see when I navigate from another page so that the code inside the **HomeScreen's** ngOnInit() doesn't hit when I don't want it to but I feel like that is bad programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that I had 2 paths set to my HomeScreen in my `app-routing.module.ts` folder which caused it to act this way. I added another route to call on `ionViewWillEnter()` and forgot to comment out the previous route.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following if you want to check for event on page navigation change.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

public class yourClassName{
  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
    // Do things when page changes routes
    })
  }

}
```